# I am Getting undefined when trying to get the value of my useParams() in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am experiencing some issues reading the value of my id when using useParams() hook.

I have 4 components:

App.js, Midlocal.js, Blogposts.js and BlogSingle.js

I have the routing set up in App.js

```
<Route path='/posts/:id' element={<PostSingle />} />
```

Then I made my Api call in MidLocal.jsx

```
  const MidLocal = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
  


  async function fetchPosts() {
    const response = await fetch("https://khg.com.ng/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
    const data = await response.json();

    setPost(data);
      

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

Sill in the same MidLocal component, I am using array.map() and passing the data as props to  component

```
<div className="mid__blog__posts">
          {post.map((item) => (
            <BlogPosts
              key={item.id}
              postId = {item.id}
              title={item.title.rendered}
              date={item.date}
              img={item.img}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```

This is the BlogPost component. Just a simple functional component where my data could be arranged the way I like it with the react router's Link feature using its TO attribute to point to the single blog page/component

```
const BlogPosts = ({postId, date, title, img}) => {
  
  return (
    <div className='post__container'>
                    <div className='post__texts'>
                        <small className='md__post__date'>{date}</small>
                        <Link to={`/posts/${postId}`}><h3 className='md__post__title'>{title}<span className='post__url__icon'><BsFillArrowRightCircleFill /></span></h3></Link>
                    </div>
      
                    <img src={img} alt={title} className='post__img'/>
                </div>
  )
}

export default BlogPosts
```

Then, in the Blog Single component,

```
const BlogSingle = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  const {postId} = useParams();

  

  console.log(postId)

  async function fetchPostContent() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://khg.com.ng/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${postId}`)
    const data = await response.json();

    setContent(data);
      
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPostContent();
  }, []);
```

console.log(postId) gives me undefined

and trying to access the value of postId gives me undefined also

```
<h1>{postId}</h1>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any route rendering path with a `postId` path parameter, so `postId` ***should*** be undefined when using `const { postId } = useParams();`. Perhaps you meant to use `const { id } = useParams();` instead. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the id in the route path accordingly. You named it `id` and you are trying to access it as `postId`. Either rename the path in route to contain `/posts/:postId` or use it as `id` in your BlogPost: `const { id } = useParams();`

Answer (score 0):

Just destructure `id` and rename as `postId`, see the following code for quick reference!

```js
const BlogSingle = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  const {id: postId} = useParams();

  

  console.log(postId)

  async function fetchPostContent() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://khg.com.ng/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${postId}`)
    const data = await response.json();

    setContent(data);
      
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPostContent();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let { id: postId } = useParams();
```

Comment: I think you should provide some explanation and context for your solution.